# How to Conditionally apply Compatibility Mode of Browser to use 7 or 9 in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

I  have a JavaScript which works in IE7, 8 Compatibility Mode, Chrome, Firefox etc. The only thing is this script doesnt work in IE8 and IE9. Any Idea?

So, i would like to set the document compatibility mode during runtime in page ,`<Head>` section. How to Conditionally set the compatibility modes?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend fixing your JavaScript. In the long run you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

If your dead set on leaving your script as it is, you can use the X-UA-Compatible meta tag (see [META Tags and Locking in Future Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817574.aspx)). That **should** make your JavaScript work (no guarantee!).

If you want to set it at run time you can declare it on your page:

```
<meta id="comp" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" runat="server" />
```

and set it in the code-behind

```
comp.Content = "IE=EmulateIE7";
```

Other browser simply ignore the tag however, so you can just put it on your page like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```